# Trimming the output of publishing

Tags: asp.net, publish

I've got a basic ASP.NET Web Application with the following publish settings:

- Publish to File System.
- Delete all existing files prior to publish - Ticked
- Precompile during publishing - Unticked
- Exclude files from the App_Data folder - Ticked

While the publish does work as expected, it seems to publish quite a bit of extra baggage.

```
\bin
    Web.config
    Web.Debug.config
    Web.Release.config
    WebServer.dll
\Properties
    AssemblyInfo.cs
    \PublishProfiles
        Release.pubxml
MyWebForm.aspx
MyWebForm.aspx.cs
MyWebForm.aspx.designer.cs
Web.config
Web.Debug.config
Web.Release.config
WebServer.csproj
WebServer.csproj.user
```

Out of all this, I'm able to remove everything but the following:

```
\bin
    WebServer.dll
MyWebForm.aspx
MyWebForm.aspx.cs
MyWebForm.aspx.designer.cs
Web.config
```

So, my question is two-fold:

- Firstly, **why** does the publish option, publish various things such as *.csproj files, or the *.config files in the bin directory etc. as the site appears to function perfectly well without this baggage. What is the purpose of these files being made public?
- Secondly, is there a way to configure the publish operation to just publish the minimum required files for the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure as to the reason behind the publish option is publishing the unrequired files, but it seems there is a very easy way to stop it. In the properties of the project under the option "Package/Publish Web" there is a group "Items to deploy", where I am able to select "Only the files required to run the project".